# Error while performing line segment detection in monteverdi

Tags: orfeo-toolbox

[image: See the error]
I am not able to perform Line Segment Detection in this stand alone tool 'Monteverdi'. I have already tried it number of times but no output generated and got the error 
''LineSegmentDetection' failed with return status -1', please help or suggest some other way to perform this task.

result og log panel plugin tab :

```
2017 Oct 28 12:53:56 : Application.logger (INFO) 
otbcli_LineSegmentDetection.bat -in F:/Results_Monteverdi/GE8_Smooth.tif -out F:/Results_Monteverdi/LSD_ge8 -ram 
128 2017 Oct 28 12:53:58 : Application.logger (FATAL) The following error occurred during OTB-application execution: 
c:\dashboard\otb\src\modules\io\vectordataio\include\otbVect‌​orDataFileWriter.txx‌​:138: Could not create IO object for file F:/Results_Monteverdi/LSD_ge8 Tried to create one of the following: OGRVectorDataIO You probably failed to set a file suffix, or set the suffix to an unsupported type
```

---

I was trying the **Line Segment Detection for GeoTIFF images** and after trying a lot was not able to get the output. Later i **converted the input images to PNG** **format** and **removed the properties and personal information** contained in the image, after that only LSD was able to process but now the output which is generated by the tool , is like the *mirror image of the line segments*. I am trying to rectify but if anyone who already tried this is welcome for the help. I have attached the images below:

[image: Line Segment Detection]

Comment: can you open the log panel message and give us the output of the plugin tab ?

Comment: 2017 Oct 28 12:53:56  :  Application.logger  (INFO) otbcli_LineSegmentDetection.bat -in F:/Results_Monteverdi/GE8_Smooth.tif -out F:/Results_Monteverdi/LSD_ge8 -ram 128 

2017 Oct 28 12:53:58  :  Application.logger  (FATAL) The following error occurred during OTB-application execution: c:\dashboard\otb\src\modules\io\vectordataio\include\otbVectorDataFileWriter.txx:138:
 Could not create IO object for file F:/Results_Monteverdi/LSD_ge8
  Tried to create one of the following:
    OGRVectorDataIO
  You probably failed to set a file suffix, or
    set the suffix to an unsupported type.

Comment: I just copied and pasted, hope you are able to get or shall i post screenshot??

Comment: The issue of mirrored images was resolved using ' Affine Transformation' plugin in QGIS . How can more line segments be extracted, i want to extract complete polygons.

Comment: please ask another question if this one is resolved by the anwer bellow. and please dont forget to check the anwer as well

Answer (score 2):

it seems to be a suffix file name error
of `F:/Results_Monteverdi/LSD_ge`

error :
**You probably failed to set a file suffix, or set the suffix to an unsupported type**

**Edit:** set `.shp` suffix instead of `.tif`

try to set the output name with a `.shp` suffix

Comment: I tried but got the same error

Comment: infact i tried using Mapla but the result was poorly generated. It created four big lines, that too not on the feature , it was on complete image